# Create external jar file and add to Netbeans 8.2

Tags: javafx, netbeans, jar

We have been trying to create JAR files from the LanguageTool (LT) Desktop version we downloaded that contains various JAR files. LT at this link made the statement that we needed all the files in these folders **libs org and META-INF** in our project. LT has repied they have no experience with Netbeans or JavaFX.
[LT Directions](http://wiki.languagetool.org/java-api)
The app was built on Windows 7 with Netbeans 8.2 as a JavaFX 8 and Maven JDK 1.8

We tried following this tutorial the author was not much for proper code formatting and failed to mention that LT is not thread safe. We seldom work with threads but think our code is correct? 
[TUTORIAL](http://www.jeramysingleton.com/add-spell-checking-to-a-javafx-app/)

To install the Class AmericanEnglish.class which is in the LT Desktop zip file we extracted we used this process
cd  C:\Users\Me\Documents\A A A A A LT UnZip\LanguageTool-4.7\LanguageTool-4.7
jar cf languagesLIBS.jar libs/*

jar cf languagesORG.jar  org/*

jar cf languagesMETA.jar META-INF/*

Here is where it gets odd to our limited knowledge of adding Dependencies to Netbeans
1.  Open the Projects tab.
2.  Right-click on Dependencies. 
3.  Select Add dependency. 
4.  Set groupId to: language(can be anything) 
5.  Set artifactId to: en (can be anything) 
6.  Set version to: 4.7(can be anything) 
7.  Click Add to continue. 
Dependency is added to pom.xml and appears under the Libraries node of Maven project. Continue: 
1.  Expand Dependencies. 
2.  Right-click on library (e.g., group.id). 
3.  Select Manually install artifact. 
4.  Set Artifact to install with the Java Archive (.jar) file path. 
5.  Click Install locally.

This process did place the AmericanEnglish.class in a JAR and it is found by Netbeans
import org.languagetool.JLanguageTool; 
import org.languagetool.language.AmericanEnglish; 
import org.languagetool.rules.RuleMatch;

Here is the error when we try to populate the JLanguageTool with AmericanEnglish

While the error NoClassDefFoundError would seem to indicate that the app can not find the
AmericanEnglish.class and that is the cause of the error ClassNotFoundException

**Our question obviously is how do we fix this ?

And are we crating the external JAR files correctly?**

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/cache/CacheLoader
at com.mycompany.maventest.CheckSpellController.lambda$ini$0(CheckSpellController.java:43)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.cache.CacheLoader
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

We also see these warnings when we Clean and Build the project
The POM for languagetool:LIBS:jar:4.7 is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for languagetool:ORG:jar:4.7 is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for languagetool:META:jar:4.7 is missing, no dependency information available

exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (unpack-dependencies) @ mavenTEST
When the Clean and Build is run we see the dependencies unpack
Here is the few lines of code that cause the error

```
static JLanguageTool langTool;

public void ini(){
  new Thread(() -> {
      langTool = new JLanguageTool(new AmericanEnglish());
  }).start();  
}
```

The ini() method is called from the initialize method

[image: AmericanEnglish class]

The necessary JAR files are in the Dependencies folder
The project imports these files

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the actual JAR and the process where you thought it was a bit ODD 
Is not the correct way to add JAR files. The extracted ZIP folder has all the gold or should we say JAR's. Here are a few screen shots and directions. That said we are still getting the NoClassDefFoundError so we will work on fixing that part of the question

Delete the three JAR's you added LIBS-4.7.jar META-4.7.jar and ORG-4.7.jar
We would also suggest opening the .m2 folder and under /repository/org/languagetool delete the languagetool folder. Do NOT worry everything will get recreated.
Right Click Dependencies folder and select Add Dependency
In the Query text field enter "org.languagetool"
Here is a comment we did not find languagetool 4.7 JAR's as central only local ? ?
You might like to try and use the central 4.6 JAR's
Expand the org.languagetool:languagetool-core folder and select the 4.7.jar
Once that JAR is in the Dependency folder Right Click ad select Copy Location
Now Right Click the same JAR once more and select Manually Install Artifact
In the Artifact To Install text box paste with a Ctrl + V 
This will take you to the location of the JAR select it and presto magic the Artifact is added
Notice the language-en-4.7 we created this JAR file because we could not find AmericanEnglish.class in any of the downloaded files. See Last screen shot
Here are the screen shots in the order to match the above direction
[image: First Step] 
[image: Second Step]
[image: Third Step]
[image: JAR's We Added]
[image: AmericanEnglish.class]

I am not holding my breath that using the downloaded 4.7 JAR,s is the best idea
You might try reaching out to Maven and Language Tool and ask why LT 4.7 is not in the repository!
Best of Luck

Comment: We tried the 4.6 JAR files no results and for some reason we had a real battle adding the opennlp JAR's We did not realize they are at org.apache.opennpl and it is only a ZIP file We are back to 4.7 local JAR's and YES the same ERROR's We will not accept as answer perhaps someone will wander by and EXPLAIN why we are still getting the NoClassDefFoundError Thanks for the heroic effort